# Length (Time) of an (non-vbr) mp3 file

Tags: parsing, mp3, compression

Im currently researching the mp3 format in order to build an mp3 decoder.
After some thinking I figured out that the simplest way to calculate the length of the song would be to divide the size by the bitrate (taking in account the size of the ID3 tag etc.), and transform the result to minutes. Using this method on a few songs I got accurate times.
I always assumed the time of the song is the length of the pure audio data, but in this method, frames are also "considered" part of the song (when calculating the time).
Also, the I understood that the audio data in the mp3 file is compressed, so when its decompressed the size of it will be larger of course, and then the time calculation seems un accurate.
Am I missing something here? because it just doesnt make any sense to me that the songs length is calculated with the compressed data and not the uncompressed ones, and frames which are a DWORD each are not ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> I always assumed the time of the song is the length of the pure audio data, but in this method, frames are also "considered" part of the song (when calculating the time). Also, the I understood that the audio data in the mp3 file is compressed, so when its decompressed the size of it will be larger of course, and then the time calculation seems un accurate.

When a media stream, such as an MP3 file, is compressed with a constant bitrate, that bitrate reflects the compressed size of the data, not the uncompressed size. So your math is fine.

What will throw you off with this approach is metadata tags (e.g, ID3) -- those are part of the file size, but are not counted in the bitrate, since they aren't audio data. Luckily, those tend to be relatively small, so they won't affect your results much.